# Dynamic multiple form insert with ng-repeat and each form has dynamic text box to get values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am working on Dynamic form insertion with ng-form and ng-repeat and trying to store multiple dynamic values using text box with in that form.
Here is my code :

```
Want to add Ingredients : <button ng-click="showIngredientForm = !showIngredientForm"  ng-class="{'red' : showIngredientForm}">{[{toggleText}]}</button>
<div ng-show="showIngredientForm">
    <div ng-repeat="formToAdd in formsToAdd" >
        <ng-form name="productFieldForm" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Option Type</label>
                <select name="ingredientName" ng-model="formToAdd.ingredientId" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Select Option Type Name</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="option in ingredientTypeList" value="{[{option._id}]}">{[{option.ingredientTypeName}]}</option>
                </select>
                <button ng-click="removeForm(formToAdd)" ng-if="formsToAdd.length > 1">Remove</button></div>
            </ng-form>
            <div ng-if="formToAdd.ingredientId">
                <div ng-repeat="itemToAdd in itemsToAdd" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <ng-form name="userFieldForm" >
                            <table>
                                <td>
                                    <label>Option Name</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Option Name" name="ingredientName" ng-model="itemToAdd.ingredientName" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]{3,25}$/" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" ng-required="true"  ng-change="verifyDuplicate()" />
<div class="validation_messages" ng-show="userFieldForm.$submitted || userFieldForm.ingredientName.$touched">
                                        <span ng-show="userFieldForm.ingredientName.$error.required">Option cannot be empty</span>
                                        <span ng-show="!userFieldForm.ingredientName.$error.required && userFieldForm.ingredientName.$error.pattern && userFieldForm.ingredientName.$dirty">Option Name Samples Cookie,Saz Mora</span>  
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='validation_messages' ng-if='itemToAdd.isDuplicate'>
                                        <span>Duplicate Not Allowed</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button ng-click="remove(itemToAdd)" ng-if="itemsToAdd.length > 1">Remove</button>
                                </td>
                            </table>
                        </ng-form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="validation_messages" ng-click="addNew()">Add new</button>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="validation_messages" ng-click="addForm()">Add new Form</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The angular controller code for this html is given below :

```
$scope.itemsToAdd = [{
    ingredientTypeName: ''
}];

$scope.formsToAdd = [];

$scope.$watch('showIngredientForm', function(){
    $scope.toggleText = $scope.showIngredientForm ? 'No' : 'Yes';
    if($scope.showIngredientForm == true){
        $scope.items = [];
        $scope.itemsToAdd = [{
            ingredientName: '',
            ingredientPrice: ''
        }];
    }
});

$scope.addForm = function(formToAdd) {
        $scope.formsToAdd.push({});
}

$scope.remove = function(itemToAdd)
{
    var index = $scope.itemsToAdd.indexOf(itemToAdd);
    $scope.itemsToAdd.splice(index, 1);
}

$scope.addNew = function() {

$scope.itemsToAdd.push({
  ingredientTypeName: '',
  ingredientPrice: ''
})
```

Any kind of help is welcome as this will help me and other programmers too ...

Comment: If i add a value inside first form textbox that is getting reflected in the other dynamic forms too ... i need the solution to get rid of this issue ...  i have achieved the dynamic insertion of textbox value with single form but when it comes for multiple forms dynamically like above then i got stuck with the issue ...

Comment: You can get some idea from it http://plnkr.co/edit/F7BGq0sfSLvKE48eDTzQ?p=preview , not exact solution it is, consider as guideline.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/MvaJlS0nOb2ukWyn6DcW?p=preview i have made the copy of my issue in plunker pls take a look at it @JigarPrajapati

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a single object as `ng-model` in input type instead use an object with several keys and values like `ng-model="itemToAdd.ingredientName[formToAdd.ingredientId]"` this will create a unique key wrt to id and assign input text value to this key which will avoid recurring of same values in next form fields.

Add `track by` to keep track of objects in the list which will help us creating new `ng-model` object keys while adding new field.

```
 <div ng-repeat="formToAdd in formsToAdd track by formToAdd.ingredientId">
 <div ng-repeat="itemToAdd in itemsToAdd track by $index">
```

and the input fields change to

```
<label>Option Name</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Option Name" name="ingredientName" ng-model="itemToAdd.ingredientName[formToAdd.ingredientId]" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]{3,25}$/" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" ng-required="true" ng-change="verifyDuplicate()" />
  <div class="validation_messages" ng-show="userFieldForm.$submitted || userFieldForm.ingredientName[formToAdd.ingredientId].$touched">
     <span ng-show="userFieldForm.ingredientName[formToAdd.ingredientId].$error.required">Option cannot be empty</span>
       <span ng-show="!userFieldForm.ingredientName[formToAdd.ingredientId].$error.required && userFieldForm.ingredientName[formToAdd.ingredientId].$error.pattern && userFieldForm.ingredientName[formToAdd.ingredientId].$dirty">Option Name Samples Cookie,Saz Mora</span>
 </div>
```

Below are the simple changes in your JS

```
$scope.itemsToAdd = [{
              ingredientName: {},//assign a new object everytime
              ingredientPrice: ''
          }];
```

In your HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     Want to add Ingredients :
    <button ng-click="showIngredientForm = !showIngredientForm" ng-class="{'red' : showIngredientForm}">{{toggleText}}</button>
    <div ng-show="showIngredientForm">
        <div ng-repeat="formToAdd in formsToAdd track by formToAdd.ingredientId">
            <ng-form name="productFieldForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Option Type</label>
                    <select name="ingredientName" ng-model="formToAdd.ingredientId" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select Option Type Name</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="option in ingredientTypeList" value="{{option._id}}">{{option.ingredientTypeName}}</option>
                    </select>
                    <button ng-click="removeForm(formToAdd)" ng-if="formsToAdd.length > 1">Remove</button>
                    <!-- <div class="validation_messages">
                        <span ng-show="validCityingredientTypeName">ingredientType Name is required</span>
                    </div> -->
                </div>
            </ng-form>
            <div ng-if="formToAdd.ingredientId">
                <div ng-repeat="itemToAdd in itemsToAdd track by $index">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <ng-form name="userFieldForm">
                            <table>
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <label>Option Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Option Name" name="ingredientName" ng-model="itemToAdd.ingredientName[formToAdd.ingredientId]" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]{3,25}$/" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" ng-required="true" ng-change="verifyDuplicate()" />
                                    <div class="validation_messages" ng-show="userFieldForm.$submitted || userFieldForm.ingredientName[formToAdd.ingredientId].$touched">
                                        <span ng-show="userFieldForm.ingredientName[formToAdd.ingredientId].$error.required">Option cannot be empty</span>
                                        <span ng-show="!userFieldForm.ingredientName[formToAdd.ingredientId].$error.required && userFieldForm.ingredientName[formToAdd.ingredientId].$error.pattern && userFieldForm.ingredientName[formToAdd.ingredientId].$dirty">Option Name Samples Cookie,Saz Mora</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='validation_messages' ng-if='itemToAdd.isDuplicate'>
                                        <span>Duplicate Not Allowed</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button ng-click="remove(itemToAdd)" ng-if="itemsToAdd.length > 1">Remove</button>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ng-form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="validation_messages" ng-click="addNew()">Add new</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="validation_messages" ng-click="addForm()">Add new Form</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Here is the **updated** **[code](https://plnkr.co/edit/V6FKZGlNHpSKYknNteXJ?p=preview)**

**UPDATE**

To remove extra boxex in every from on click of add new in another form add below code in JS

```
    $scope.addNew = function(key) {
            if ($scope.itemsToAdd[key]== null) {
                $scope.itemsToAdd[key] = [];
            }
            $scope.itemsToAdd[key].push({
                ingredientName: {},
                ingredientPrice: ''
            });
        };
  $scope.remove = function(itemToAdd,key) {
        var index = $scope.itemsToAdd[key].indexOf(itemToAdd);
        $scope.itemsToAdd[key].splice(index, 1);
    };
```

In HTML for the inner `ng-repeat` to `itemsToAdd`

```
<div ng-repeat="itemToAdd in itemsToAdd[formToAdd.ingredientId] track by $index">
```

Instead of a list we are basically creating `itemsToAdd` object `{}` and assigning it a key with a list object which holds new items for each and every form individually.

Comment: Hi @Angular_10 i have checked your code but still the issue persists like the duplication of text boxes and its values in forms ex. 2nd and 3rd forms and goes.

Comment: You can't have new forms more than the number of values in dropdown as the key will be repeated in ng-model so ttry increasing drop down values

Comment: will you pls help in that aspect to get the exact output for my requirement so that it'll help for others too ... i have tried your suggestion but still can't get it ... it'll be great if you reproduce your output in plunker ...

Comment: Have you tried the plunker I have provided in the solution ? Did that help ?

Comment: ya that helped me but still i cant get rid of the duplicate text boxes that appear in each forms ... i had came up with an update take a  look at this plunk and help me to achieve the output https://plnkr.co/edit/K1RQyq?p=preview

Comment: By taking your suggestion i have restricted the drop down values and now everything is fine except the dynamic text box creation in each form ... looking for your reply ...

Comment: man you really rocked it !!! thanks for your help ... will ask you if i have any query during the implementation of this in my project ...

Comment: i have enhance the solution with complete validation with  efficiency ... check the plunk provided ...